# JAAS implementation with Wildfly 8.2.1 and EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, ejb, wildfly-8, jaas

Hi I want to try JAAS in EJB and I do not know how I can do this but I am imagining that I have to use something similar with `request.login` when using Form Authentication in Web Applications.

I am using WildFly 8.2.1 Final, eclipse luna.

Here is what I have already done.

**standalone.xml**

```
<security-realm name="myJdbcRealm">
    <authentication>
        <jaas name="myJdbcSecurityDomain" />
    </authentication>
</security-realm>

<security-domain name="myJdbcSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/appmysql_ds"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select user_password from users where username = ?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role_name, 'Roles' from user_roles where username = ?"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
            <module-option name="hashCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>     
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

**jboss-ejb3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:s="urn:security:1.1"
               version="3.1"
               impl-version="2.0">

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <s:security>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <s:security-domain>myJdbcSecurityDomain</s:security-domain>
            <s:run-as-principal>Admin</s:run-as-principal>
            <s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>false</s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>
        </s:security>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:ejb-jar >
```

**LoginImpl**

```
    @Stateless
    @PermitAll
    public class LoginImpl implements LoginRemote, LoginLocal {
        public void login() throws EJBException {
            LoginContext loginContext; // here I do not know what to do
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE - NEW LoginImpl.java**

Here is the new `LoginImpl.java`, and I logged in successfully but the problem now is that when I try to call `getCallerPrincipal()` is gives me `anonymous`

```
    @Stateless
    public class LoginImpl implements LoginRemote, LoginLocal {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    public void login(String username, String password) throws LoginException {
        MyCallbackHandler sec = new MyCallbackHandler(username, password.toCharArray());
        PrivilegedAction privilegedAction = new MyPrivilegeAction("admin");

        LoginContext loginContext = new LoginContext("myJdbcSecurityDomain", sec);
        loginContext.login();
        Subject user = loginContext.getSubject();
        Subject.doAs(user, privilegedAction);
        System.out.println("Login Successful");
    }

    public void printPricipal() {
        System.out.println("Principal : " + sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal());
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some examples in my [arquillian-security-demo](https://github.com/sfcoy/demos/tree/master/arquillian-security-demo)